# Get File Size of Modified Image Before Writing to Disk

Tags: c#, image, gdi+, system.drawing

I'm doing a conversion from *.jpg* to *.png* in `System.Drawing` and one thing that I've found is that this conversion tends to make the resulting converted *.png* much larger than the *.jpg* original. Sometimes more than 10x larger after converting to *.png*.

Given that seems to always be the case (unless you know of a way around this), is there any way to determine the file size of that *.png* before it is saved to disk? For example, maybe write it to a stream first and then get that stream size? How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write to a MemoryStream and calculate the size of it, then write it to the FileSystem.

Although: There might be a better way.

Comment: How would I calculate the size of a MemoryStream?

Comment: If you convert the JPG into the MemoryStream, the "Position" property should tell you your location within the steam (and thus, the size).

Comment: Doesn't the length property provides the size (approximate) ?